# Can't do any changes to a job in SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000, jobs

I have a job in my SQL 2000 server, this job is used to execute a DTS, i want to change the schedule of this job.

but every time i try to change of delete or stop this job i get the error message

```
ERROR 14274: Cannot add, update, or delete a job (or its steps or schedules) that originated from an MSX server. The job was not saved.
```

i have a system shutdown coming up in the weekend and i cant stop this job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be facing this issue ...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281642

> After the Windows server name been changed, when trying to update or
>   delete the jobs previously created in a SQL Server 2000 instance, you
>   may receive the following error message:
>
> `Error 14274: Cannot add, update, or delete a job (or its steps or
>   schedules) that originated from an MSX server. The job was not saved.`

Here are the suggested steps to *workaround* the issue ...

> The best way to handle this problem after the rename process is to
>   follow these steps:
>
> 1. Rename the server back to the original name.
> 2. Script out all of the jobs and then delete them.
> 3. Rename the server to the new name.
> 4. Add back the jobs by running the script generated from step 2.

Additionally you can find more discussion/suggestions here ...

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/12/20/sql-server-fix-error-14274-cannot-add-update-or-delete-a-job-or-its-steps-or-schedules-that-originated-from-an-msx-server-the-job-was-not-saved/

Comment: Thanks, i just applied the script "update sysjobs set originating_server = 'thenewservername';" and it worked, i didnt want to change my server name because it will effect other things. but thanks for the link